# Decoding base64 Image String in Php

Tags: php, android, json, image

I am building an Android App, When registering the user has to supply their information among which is their profile picture, the App then Encodes the image to Base64 String and adds it to an array list together with the rest of all other information supplied, my problem is decoding the Base64 String on the server side to an Image and saving the image name into the database, if the user did not upload an image it should set a default image, I have tried several methods but am all have failed, if I do not include a Base64 image String in my JSON post the app runs smoothly meaning I am messing up on decoding the image and setting it, if I run the whole Php code in a browser it works perfectly, so am stuck, Where is the phone going wrong?

If an image is supplied it executes this code

```
  if (imgPath !=null)

        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            final Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath, options);
           ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String profile_pic= Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);


            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nrc", nrc));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", dob));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cell", cell));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile", profile_pic));
```

if an Image is not supplied it executes this code:

```
  try {

                String profile_pic = null;
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nrc", nrc));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", dob));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cell", cell));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("profile", profile_pic));
```

and on my Server side the following Code is to execute once data is received:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if(!empty($_POST['profile']) || $_POST['profile'] == null)
    {
       $image = $_POST['profile'];
        $binary=base64_decode($image);
        $source = imagecreatefromstring($binary);       
    }

    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))   
    {

        // Create some data that will be the JSON response 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please Make Sure All Fields Are filled";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    //now lets update what :user should be
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username']
    );


    try {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $Destination = 'avatars';
    if(!isset($_POST['profile']) || 
       !is_uploaded_file($_POST['profile']['tmp_name']) || 
       $_POST['profile'] == null )
    {
        $NewImageName= 'default.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($_POST['profile']['tmp_name'], "$Destination/$NewImageName");
    }else{
        $RandomNum   = rand(0, 9999999999);
        $ImageName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_POST['profile']['name']));
        $ImageType = $_POST['profile']['type'];
        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        $ImageName = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
        $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;
        move_uploaded_file($_POST['profile']['tmp_name'],   "$Destination/$NewImageName");
    }

    $sql5="UPDATE users SET propic='$NewImageName' WHERE username = ':username'";
    $sql6="INSERT INTO users (propic) VALUES ('$NewImageName') WHERE username = ':username'";

    $query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, 
                                  fname, 
                                  lname,
                                password,
                                  email,
                                  city,
                                  dob,
                                  nrc,
                                  cell,
                                  propic) 
                          VALUES ( :user,
                                   :fnam,
                                   :lnam,
                                   :pass, 
                                   :emai,
                                   :cit,
                                   :do, 
                                   :nr,  
                                   :cel,
                                   :NewImageName )";

    //Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':fnam' => $_POST['fname'],
        ':lnam' => $_POST['lname'] ,
        ':pass' => md5($_POST['password']),
        ':emai' => $_POST['email'],
        ':cit'  => $_POST['city'],
        ':do'   => $_POST['dob'],
        ':nr'   => $_POST['nrc'],
        ':cel' => $_POST['cell'],
        ':NewImageName' =>$NewImageName);



    //time to run our query, and create the user
    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I would say the problem is that you are using functions like `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()` which are only relevant if you are using a standard file upload mechanism. However you are just passing the image as a base64 encoded variable on the normal POST a fieldname and variable mechanism. So `$_POST['profile']` is just a normal field that you need to convert back to an image using base64decode. You should then write it to disk like a normal file.

Comment: Thank You, how can I implement that looking at my current approach

Comment: `$binary=base64_decode($image);`. $binary contains your image bytes. So just save them to file and you are done. Use file_put_contents().